# How to run gradle tasks from specific ".gradle" file with terminal in android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, gradlew, gradle-task

I am new to writing gradle tasks.

I have added a `.gradle` file into root of my project in this `gradle` file there are some tasks, my question is how to run these `tasks` via `Terminal` in android studio?

[image: gradle-task]

When i run a task with Terminal in android studio it has return following error:

```
Task 'testTask' not found in root project 'TestProject'.
```

Comment: Did you add `apply from: "$rootDir/test.gradle"` in any `build.gradle`?

Comment: @DeKaNszn I have not added 'apply from: "$rootDir/test.gradle"' in 'build.gradle' what is doing this code?

Comment: This code add all content of `test.gradle` to your `build.gradle`

Comment: @DeKaNszn thank you very much the problem is solved

Comment: I've put answer and you can mark this question as solved now

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We must add any custom gradle scripts to build.gradle using `apply from`
For example:

```
apply from: "$rootDir/test.gradle"
```

Answer (score 3):

Just to explain a bit, following @DeKaNszn answer:

Depending on where is the script situated, you will need to extend your `build.gradle` with it.

If the script is in the root, yes including

```
apply from: "$rootDir/test.gradle"
```

is going to extend you the script you have applied it to, then **if your `test.gradle` is in the root and you want to access the task defined in that script from your project, or any subproject**, you will need to apply it in the `build.gradle` in this project, because otherwise gradle will not read it automatically and configure the task.

`build.gradle` is read automatically, therefore extending it with your script is going to configure the task you want to use and have it visible for Gradle.

---

There is a kind of a convention, to put your scripts in the `gradle` directory, and keep `build.gradle` and `settings.gradle` only in the root, but is just a preference.

But if you would like to follow this idea you will need to give it a path where to apply from, like above, and always use Gradle variables pointing to directories. `$rootDir`, `$buildDir`, etc.